# self is not defined error when i am using jodti-react text edior in nextjs project

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, angularjs, next.js

self is not defined error when i use jodti-react in nextjs project

```
import React, { useState, useRef, useMemo } from "react";
import Dashborad from "./Dashborad";
import JoditEditor from "jodit-react";
import dynamic from "next/dynamic";

export default function edit() {
  const editor = useRef();
  const [content, setContent] = useState("");

  return (
    <Dashborad>
      <JoditEditor
        ref={editor}
        value={content}
        tabIndex={1} // tabIndex of textarea
        onBlur={(newContent) => setContent(newContent)} // preferred to use only this option to update the content for performance reasons
        onChange={(newContent) => setContent(newContent)}
      />
    </Dashborad>
  );
}
```

}

how to solve this error ?

Answer (score 3):

create jodit.js file

```
import { useRef, useMemo } from 'react'
import JoditEditor from 'jodit-react'

const Jodit = ({ content, setContent }) => {
  const editor = useRef(null)

  return (
    <JoditEditor
       ref={editor}
        value={content}
        tabIndex={1} // tabIndex of textarea
        onBlur={(newContent) => setContent(newContent)} // preferred to use only this option to update the content for performance reasons
        onChange={(newContent) => setContent(newContent)}
    />
  )
}
export default Jodit
```

Use dynamic import

```
  const Jodit = dynamic(() => import('./Jodit'), { ssr: false })
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this solution it's more easy

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic';
```

Following this command add this command in your file

```
const JoditEditor = dynamic(() => import('jodit-react'), { ssr: false });
```

To use **Jodit Editor** in your code, keep using it the same way. It'll will work

```
<JoditEditor
    ref={editor}
    value={content}
    tabIndex={1} // tabIndex of textarea
    onBlur={(newContent) => setContent(newContent)} // preferred to use only this option to update the content for performance reasons
    onChange={(newContent) => setContent(newContent)}
  />
```

Hope this helps